# C++ Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) Error - Casting Pointers/Returning Function Value to Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault, void-pointers

I am new to C++ Programming as well as thread implementation. My goal was to design a program that uses two threads to add the elements in 2 subranges (elements 0-9 and elements 10-19) of one array, then add the values returned by the threads to formulate the sum of all the elements of the array. I've complied the following code and based on my limited knowledge of the "gdb" debugger it seems my issue is with the pointers in sum_function. I cannot figure out my mistake. Any help is appreciated!!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

int arguments[20]; 

void *sum_function (void *ptr);

int main (void) {

pthread_t thread1, thread2;
int total, sum1, sum2 = 0;
int lim1 = 10;
int lim2 = 20;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    cin >> arguments[i];

sum1 = pthread_create ( &thread1, NULL, sum_function, (void*) lim1);
sum2 = pthread_create ( &thread2, NULL, sum_function, (void*) lim2);

pthread_join (thread1, NULL);
pthread_join (thread2, NULL);

total = sum1 + sum2;

cout << "OUTPUT \n" << total << "\n";

return (0);
}

void *sum_function (void *lim) {

int sum = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < (*(int*)lim); j++)
    sum += arguments[j];
return (void*) sum;

}
```

Comment: `pthread_create` function return `0` if success, otherwise error number. you are assigning those values to `sum1` and `sum2` to get the total. probably not what you want.

Comment: @shan...you're correct, not my intention. I'm going to look up how to get the "sum" values from each thread. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sum1 = pthread_create ( &thread1, NULL, sum_function, (void*) lim1);
sum2 = pthread_create ( &thread2, NULL, sum_function, (void*) lim2);
```

This passes `10` and `20`, cast to a `void *` to the threads.

```
for (int j = 0; j < (*(int*)lim); j++)
```

This casts the `10` and `20` to an `int *` and then dereferences them. But they're not valid pointers.

If you want the thread to receive an address, you have to pass it an address. If you want to pass the thread a value, code it to receive a value.

You can fix this two ways:

1) Consistently pass and expect pointers:

```
sum1 = pthread_create ( &thread1, NULL, sum_function, (void*) &lim1);
sum2 = pthread_create ( &thread2, NULL, sum_function, (void*) &lim2);
...
for (int j = 0; j < (*(int*)lim); j++)
```

Notice that `pthread_create` is now passing the thread a pointer, and the thread is now dereferencing that pointer.

2) Consistently pass and expect values:

```
sum1 = pthread_create ( &thread1, NULL, sum_function, (void*) lim1);
sum2 = pthread_create ( &thread2, NULL, sum_function, (void*) lim2);
...
for (int j = 0; j < ((int)lim); j++)
```

Notice that `pthread_create` is now passing an integer value, and the thread is now expecting an integer value.

Comment: Thanks David. I tried revising the code to pass values instead of pointers  `( &thread1, NULL, sum_function, lim1);`...`void *sum_function (int lim)`...but it wouldn't even compile. Seems that's not what you meant. Could please you clarfiy? Thanks

Comment: You can't change the function prototypes, just change the *values*. You already *pass* the value, so just change the thread function to receive the value. For example: `for (int j = 0; j < ((int)lim); j++)` (See updates.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly related to the title. i'm addressing your current situation. You may create a struct.

```
struct args
{
    int arr_limit;
    int local_result;
};
```

then populate this struct as you want, and pass the addresses as a `void` pointer to the `pthread_create` function. you can solve both your problems.. hope this helps...